# Activate notification led programmatically in Android

Tags: android, notifications, led

I'm trying to activate Android's notification led programmatically. Usually, it activates by itself upon notification and deactivates when notification is cleared. I'd like to activate it programmatically, making it indipendent, but I see there's no documentation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can't do it. You can only use notification led when user receives a notification and the screen is turned off.